# Is there any ssh client supporting java.nio.channels.SocketChannel?

Tags: java, ssh, client, selector, nio

I developed a proxy application, by which users can telnet to it and send a "connect to xxx" command to connect to a ssh server. I use JSch as my ssh client:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(username, ip, 22);
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
InputStream inp = channel.getInputStream();
OutputStream oup = channel.getOutputStream();
MyReader myReader = new MyReader(userOutputStream, inp);
new Thread(myReader).start();
MyWriterThread myWriter = new MyWriter(userInputStream, oup);
new Thread(myWriter).start();
```

then deal with input and output respectively in these two new threads. But the proxy's performance dropped rapidly with the increase of user amount for too many concurrent threads. So I want to use java.nio.channels.Selector and SocketChannel to decrease thread amount. However I can't find a ssh client supporting java.nio.*(e.g.: JSch, Apache sshd, sshtools, etc.). Does any other ssh client supporting java nio? Or are there some methods can connecting input/output stream with Selector and SocketChannel?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How many concurrent users do you have? Threads should scale to a few hundred easily -- make sure you are terminating threads in a timely manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2015 there is an nio fork of JSCH:

https://github.com/lucastheisen/jsch-nio

I've used it and it does improve throughput significantly.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Parallec](http://www.parallec.io/) by eBay, which uses [Akka](http://akka.io/).